# Calculating a volume integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> I need to calculate $\int\limits_Kz^2 dx\ dy\ dz$ with $$K=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 | x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 4, \ \ x^2+y^2\geq 1\}.$$

We use cylindrical coordinates and see:
$$r^2+z^2 \leq 4 \; \text{and} \; r^2\geq 1\Rightarrow  -2\leq z \leq 2  \; \text{and} \; 1\leq r \leq \sqrt{4-z^2}.$$
So we get
$$\begin{align}\int\limits_Kz^2\ dx\ dy\ dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-2}^2\int\limits_1^{\sqrt{4-z^2}} z^2 r \cdot dr\ dz\ d\varphi\\
&=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\int_{-2}^2\int_1^{\sqrt{4-z^2}} z^2 r \cdot dr\ dz\ d\varphi=2\pi\int\limits_{-2}^2z^2\frac{1}{2}[(4-z^2)-1 ]dz\\
&=\pi\int\limits_{-2}^2 3z^2-z^4 dz=\pi[z^3-\frac{1}{5}z^5]_{-2}^2\\
&=\pi[(2^3-2^5/5)-(-8-2^5/5)]=\pi(16-64/5)\end{align}$$

Apparently, and this might be wrong (since I noted it in a hurry), the result is $\frac{6\sqrt{3}}{5}\pi$. No idea where I should get a root from.

Comment: Your error is in thinking that $-2 \leq z \leq +2$ given that the cylinder is removed from the sphere.

Comment: Yeah I actually though about how it looks properly but no idea why I did that borders wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $r^2\ge 1$, the $z$ limit is $z^2\le3$.  The last step in the integration is $\pi[z^3-\frac{z^5}{5}]_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{6\sqrt{3}}{5}\pi$.

Comment: I struggle a bit getting why $z^2\leq 3$ though. I mean, it's clear from the math, but I keep thinking: I do have a ball of radius 2, so the cylinder has to go from $-2$ to $2$. Any hints on what's wrong with that thought? Edit: Actually it makes sense: The wider the hole, the flatter the "ball/donut". Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way to see it is to look at in two dimensions $(r,z)$.  The sphere becomes a circle of radius $2$, while the cylinder cuts out the part of the circle for $-1\le r\le 1$  If you look at the integrand after the $r$ integral, it becomes negative for $z^2\gt 3$

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer (so please don't downvote)... but this is to show the OP the error in reasoning:

[image]

Comment: I know that it looks like that. Thanks though!

Comment: While you might know that the region looks like that, you did not understand it with enough precision to see that the limits on $z$ were not $-2 \leq z \leq +2$—the source of your error